# Inherit a base class and an interface same time

Tags: c#, interface, base-class

In this course project, the teacher created an **abstract base class (EfEntityRepositoryBase)** for data access, a **concrete class for each entity (ProductDal)** that inherits abstract base class and implements an **interface (IEntityRepository)**. ProductDal also has its **interface (IProductDal)** which also implements IEntityRepository.

What is the use case for doing it? **I can't understand the point of IProductDal implementing IEntityRepository, since ProductDal already inherits the abstract base class that implements the same interface.** So if any function updates in IEntityRepository, should be no problem. If someone can explain so would be great. Below abstract class and interfaces code.

```
public class ProductDal : EfEntityRepositoryBase<Product>, IProductDal{ }

public interface IEntityRepository<T>
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    List<T> GetAll(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression = null);
    T GetById(Expression<Func<T, bool>> expression);
}

public interface IProductDal: IEntityRepository<Product>
{
}

public class EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity> : IEntityRepository<TEntity> where TEntity : class, IEntity, new()
{
    public void Add(TEntity entity)
    {
        using (BookStoreTrackerDBContext context = new BookStoreTrackerDBContext())
        {
            var addedEntity = context.Entry(entity);
            addedEntity.State = EntityState.Added;
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show EfEntityRepositoryBase<T> class too pls

Comment: Hi, added EfEntityRepositoryBase<T> class code in text too.

Comment: Could you also include the code for `IEntity` please?

Comment: (The abstract class is not marked `abstract`.) Your are correct the class written at the top, `public class ProductDal : EfEntityRepositoryBase<Product>, IProductDal`, becomes an `IEntityRepository<Product>` in two ways (one through its base class, and the other one through the base interface of the interface it implements). This is allowed, at least. I am not sure if it is any problem. Maybe it is. At least it does not seem like any interface member has more than one implementation.

Comment: Here is [a simpler example (C# source encoded in URL)](https://tio.run/##dY6xCgIxEET7fMVyVQJ613tokVQHCoKFdYyrLJyJ3OYUEb89BqNoYzsz7zGOp45dSiOTP8LmxhFPrSAfcThYh9CJu7gE2sNKqlY8hOstM2iYfZuuzh3MF2CC59BjvR0o4pI8ykpXP5TJlIamgckLPo@7nhx87H8Mphg42pjHRbTO9DsotCVfBFJ2Snq8gpFKqbqcTukJ) where a class can "re-implement" an interface (if you uncomment `, I`). This is also allowed, and also maybe not a good idea. I know this is not what you ask, but in my example it could be better to have `virtual` member in the base class `B` and override it in inheriting class `C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is easy to understand that you feel, when looking at your provided example, tempted to call out the `IProductDal` interface as being redundant. In fact, it doesn't add any extra members to the type `ProductDal` because the interface `IProductDal` and the generic class `EfEntityRepositoryBase` are defined with the same generic parameter type `Product`. Since those teaching examples are not set in context of real application code, their real intentions or ideas behind them are not easy to understand.

---

As a side note, you should know that in case the class `EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity>` would be defined with a different generic parameter type than `Product` e.g., `int`, `ProductDal` would have two implementations/member overloads of the `IEntityRepository<T>` interface.
For example:

```
public class ProductDal : EfEntityRepositoryBase<int>, IProductDal
{ 
  // Implementation of IProductDal. The EfEntityRepositoryBase type provides another 'int' overload
  public void Add(Product entity) {}
}

void Main()
{
  var productDal = new ProductDal();
  
  // Implementation of IEntityRepository<int> provided by class EfEntityRepositoryBase<int>
  productDal.Add(6);

  // Implementation of 'IProductDal' (provided by class 'ProductDal')  
  productDal.Add(new Product());
}
```

You can see that your provided example shows a special case where the `EfEntityRepositoryBase<TEntity>` already provides the implementation for the `IEntityRepository<Product>` and the IProductDal interfaces.

---

Back to your example: if you make use of type casting, you will find another use case for having the alledgedly redundant type definitions:

Given is your `ProductDal` type with the following class signature

```
public class ProductDal : EfEntityRepositoryBase<int>, IProductDal
```

You have now multiple types available to access the implementation of `IEntityRepository<Product>`

```
void Main()
{
  // Create an instance of ProducDal
  ProductDal productDal = new ProductDal();

  /* Use the instance of ProductDal with multiple overloads 
     to show implicit type casting */
  UseProductDal(productDal);
  UseIProductDal(productDal);
  UseIEntityRepository(productDal);
  UseEntityRepository(productDal);
}

void UseProductDal(ProductDal productDal)
{
  // Instantiate the argument
  var product = new Product(); 
  productDal.Add(product);
}

void UseIProductDal(IProductDal productDal)
{
  // Instantiate the argument
  var product = new Product(); 
  productDal.Add(product);
}

void UseIEntityRepository(IEntityRepository<Product> productDal)
{
  // Instantiate the argument
  var product = new Product(); 

  productDal.Add(product);
}

void UseEntityRepositoryBase(EntityRepositoryBase<Product> productDal)
{
  // Instantiate the argument
  var product = new Product(); 
  productDal.Add(product);
}
```

This shows how to make use of the implicit type casting and also how to use interfaces.
You now see that although `EntityRepositoryBase<Product>` already implements `IEntityRepository<Product>`, still having `ProductDal` additionally implement the `IProductDal` interface makes perfect sense in order to enable `ProductDal` to be used where only the `IProductDal` interface is known.

---

You can make use of interface casting to hide members. For example if you add exclusive members to each interface then this members are only accessible when casting the implementor to the corresponding interface:

```
public interface IEntityRepository<T>
{
  void Add(T entity);  
}

public interface IProductDal: IEntityRepository<Product>
{
  // Exclusive member. Will be only visible when accessed through this interface. 
  int GetProductCount();
}
```

Given is your `ProductDal` type with the following class signature

```
public class ProductDal : IEfEntityRepository<int>, IProductDal

void Main()
{
  // Create an instance of ProducDal
  ProductDal productDal = new ProductDal();

  /* Use the instance of ProductDal with multiple overloads 
     to show implicit type casting */
  UseProductDal(productDal);
  UseIProductDal(productDal);
  UseIEntityRepository(productDal);
  UseEntityRepository(productDal);
}

// All implemented interfaces are visible since there is no casting involved.
// All members are referenced via the implementor type ProductDal.
void UseProductDal(ProductDal productDal)
{
  // Instantiate the argument
  var product = new Product(); 
  
  productDal.Add(product);
  int productCount = productDal.getProductCount();
}

// Only 'IProductDal' is visible since there is an implicit cast to an interface type involved
void UseIProductDal(IProductDal productDal)
{
  // Instantiate the argument
  var product = new Product(); 

  // 'Add()' is provided by 'IEntityRepository<T>', 
  // which is implemented by 'IProductDal' and therefore "visible"
  productDal.Add(product); 

  // 'GetProductCount()' is provided by 'IProductDal'
  int productCount = productDal.GetProductCount();
}

// Only 'IEntityRepository<T>' is visible since there is an implicit cast to the interface type 
void UseIEntityRepository(IEntityRepository<Product> productDal)
{
  // Instantiate the argument
  var product = new Product(); 

  productDal.Add(product);

  // 'GetProductCount()' is only available via the 'IProductDal' interface. 
  // It's not visible here.
  //int productCount = productDal.GetProductCount();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

At the root of this question is how interfaces are used in dependency injection and mocking / unit testing.

Let's look at what each of these classes and interfaces give you...

#### ProductDal

This class contains the logic for interacting with `Product` instances held in your data store.

#### IProductDal

Where you want to use a `ProductDal` to interact with `Product` instances in your data store, declaring it as a `IProductDal` instead allows your unit tests for code which is dependent on `ProductDal` to create mock instances of `IProductDal` which behave however is needed for your unit tests, so that your unit tests for code which uses `ProductDal` aren't dependent on an actual database. In your production code you can use dependency injection to inject a real `ProductDal` where an `IProductDal` is declared.

#### IEntityRepository

This looks like a fairly generic interface specifying some basic CRUD operations which might be useful for any entity which you might hold in a data store, and it's agnostic of what the type of data store is (e.g. SQL server / MongoDB / Cassandra / imp with a filing cabinet full of notebooks) or what Object Relational Mapper (e.g. Entity Framework / NHibernate) you might be using to access the data store.

#### EfEntityRepositoryBase

This abstract class contains an implementation of the basic CRUD methods in `IEntityRepository` which is specific to Entity Framework, to save you repeating those methods in your `ProductDal` etc classes. You could have another abstract class with implementations of those methods for another ORM (e.g. NHibernate), and if you were to switch from using Entity Framework to using NHibernate then you'd just need to change the inheritance of each of your `ProductDal` etc classes so that they derive from `NHibernateEntityRepository<T>` rather than `EfEntityRepositoryBase<T>`.

#### But back to the question...

> I can't understand the point of `IProductDal` implementing `IEntityRepository`, since `ProductDal` already inherits the abstract base class that implements the same interface

If you're using `ProductDal` rather than `IProductDal` wherever you want to interact with `Product` instances in your data store, then it doesn't really make any difference in your production code, but your unit tests are going to be really difficult to write, and probably slow to run and rather flaky too, because they'll depend on a real data store which is in exactly the right state at the start of each test case.

If instead you're using `IProductDal` to interact with `Product` instances in your data store, and using dependency injection to use a `ProductDal` where a `IProductDal` is needed by your production code (so that unit tests for that code aren't dependent on a real data store), you'll hit a different problem. Consider this unit test (which uses the Moq mocking framework, but the same issue exists regardless of what mocking framework you use):

```
[Fact]
public void Test1()
{
    var mockProductDal = new Mock<IProductDal>();
    mockProductDal.Setup(m => m.GetAll(null))
                  .Returns(new List<Product> { new Product { } });
}
```

In the above test, the compiler only understands `m => m.GetAll` if `IProductDal` is derived from `EfEntityRepositoryBase` (which is where the `GetAll` method is defined).

Similar problems will also turn up in any of your production code which uses `IProductDal` - after all, that code is a consumer of `IProductDal` / `ProductDal` in the same way that the above unit test is.

#### In short...

Reference the interface rather than the implementation in your production code. Use dependency injection in your production code to inject the real implementation, and mock the interface in your unit tests to remove dependencies on external resources such as data stores. If you do this then you also need to do apparently strange things like making `Interface1` implement `Interface2` when the class which implements `Interface1` is derived from a class which implements `Interface2`. But it'll make your unit tests easier to write, and better, and better unit tests can only be a good thing.

Comment: But the reason *why* `IProductDal` implements `IEntityRepository<Product>` is to enable dependency injection and mocking in unit tests. Maybe a discussion of *how* to do dependency injection and mocking is a bit advanced for this particular question, but I feel that an explanation of *why* this is a good pattern to follow is in order.

Comment: Interfaces don't exist because of dependenc injection or mocking. In fact you don't mock interfaces but classes i.e. the implementations of interfaces. Interfaces are a fundamental concept in OO languages. They provide a contract. Interfaces allow to wite code without knowing actual implementations. Interfaces are useful to enable polymorphism, IoC, type hierarchies while avoiding multi-inheritance, application or architectural interfaces, extensibility, encapsulation and data hiding.

Comment: Dependency Injection is only a design pattern that makes use of interfaces like Abstract Factory, Template, Strategy, Repository and many more. Programming against interfaces doe not mean Dependency Injection. Dependency Injection is a design pattern to enable extensibility. While programmingf against interfaces enbles  flexibile code and "generic" behavior of operations: a method that operates on a concrete ProductDal can only be used with this type, whereas a method that operates on the interface IProductDal can be used with every type as long it implements the interface.

Comment: That's the true magic. For example IDisposable does not exist to enable Dependency Injection or mocking. It enables a framework: a library that implements a complete logic which is extended by client code that implements the expected interface types. You don't know why IProductDal implements an interface - the author knows.

Comment: @sbridewell Maybe that is why teacher build structure like this. I can't be sure at this point, but i will take a look here when project advances.

Comment: I guess only the teacher really knows *why* they implemented it like this. My answer only explains why *I* might implement something like this. @BionicCode has made some really good points which consider the question from a broader perspective than my slight obsession with unit testing, and I don't disagree with anything they've written here.

Comment: _"my slight obsession with unit testing"_, You got me :D